# Migrating a VS 2017 project to Embarcadero

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, builder, migrating

Dear Embarcadero users,

I am trying to migrate my VS 2017 project to Embarcadero but so far invain. You should link to "https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/607c7811-6c85-45f5-afd7-eb74c0f55d31/unable-to-compile-a-release-version-on-visual-studio-2017?forum=vssetup#bbe96e62-7a42-4501-9565-0a661165ac5a" to understand why I wanted to migrate to Embarcadero. According to Darran Rowe I succeeded in my debug built by Visual Studio's compiler's zero initializing of (not [properly] initialized )local variables. My release built succeeded also but it failed my (always executed )test by solving 6.000 mathematical highschool(+) exercises. Darran Rowe stated that the code's behaviour will be random in a release built. So wrong solutions and even runtime errors will be abundant. BUT I CAN'T DEBUG THIS RELEASE BUILT. So I tried Embarcadero and succeeded in compiling error free a debug built  but received the next message in the end when linking:
1.[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_wmain' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\EMBARCADERO\STUDIO\19.0\LIB\WIN32\RELEASE\C0X32W.OBJ
2.[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'HtmlHelpW' referenced from F:\BORLAND\LST\WIN32\DEBUG\LST_MAIN.OBJ
3.[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link
These errors prevented me from a successful building of course! The code I compiled was in VS 2017 sufficient to run my program. It is without MFC, SDI and MDI completely! So I created all windows, menu's, toolbars and so on! Of course I can't exactly know what C0C32W.OBJ is but it might be a precompiled source/include code file. I checked of course a few samples and the only common thing I detected were some lines with: Appplication->Initialize() and Application->Run() and both of them missing in my VS 2017 [w]WinMain() function.
1. The Embarcadero linker seems to suspect an MSDOS main() function but I intended a Windows [w]WinMain() function! I don't know how to convince the linker my attempt should be concerning a Windows project! I detected of course the "WIN32\RELEASE\" part of the path to  C0X32W.OBJ!
2. My code is still containing Visual Studio's call to the Windows API HtmlHelp()!
3. Of course the Embarcadero linker will stop trying to link. And Embarcadero will remain failing to help me to create an Embarcadero executable! That will possibly leave my question "Will it be possible to migrate a VS program to Embarcadero?" unsolved, neither confirmed nor  denied! WHO MIGHT HELP ME?
Perhaps Embarcadero is also applying this same Microsoft idea about zero initializing of uninitialized/improperly initialized local variables(in a debug built) but I don't expect so and it would amaze me! But if so please tell me so I could finish my queste! Else I expect only the MainWindow might be a problem in an Embarcadero executable! There might even be more than one of them: my own and Embarcadero's MainWindow!

Ton Epskamp.

Comment: This is a fairly incomprehensible wall of text I'm afraid.  Perhaps the best thing to do would be to post the smallest reproducible test case in VS2017 that exhibits the difference you see between release/dbg versions and go from there.  Switching compilers in the hope of fixing an unknown issue is unlikely to work out well.

Comment: Dear Alex K., I am sorry for the big text from Wordpad loosing its format. I would like to send you my text in another way. My email is a.epskamp@ziggo.nl. If you want to help me contact me so I can send my text to you again! I am a kind of desparate!